# Xamarin Forms iOS custom renderer view controller hierarchy

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am trying to challenge the error message show below when running Xamarin Forms iOS app:

> Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is
>   discouraged

In my custom view ViewRenderer, at some point of time, I am trying to present some UIViewController. Let's take a very simple example:

```
ViewController.PresentViewController(new UIViewController(), true, null);
```

The above gives this warning.

I can see that iOS ViewRenderer provides a point for the [ViewController](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/VisualElementRenderer.cs#L147) via VisualElementRenderer.

It is even overriden by [ListViewRenderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/ListViewRenderer.cs#L33).

But I cannot make it work in my renderer.
I made exactly the same in my view renderer as it is in ListViewRenderer.
It looks like not being used to connect my view controller with the parent. What is it for?

How can I make my view controller to be part of the **root view controller hierarchy**?

**Update 1**

It looks like the view controller hierarchy is maintained as long as the view renderer provides the view controller.

[VisualElementPackager](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/VisualElementPackager.cs#L74) does this:

```
protected virtual void OnChildAdded(VisualElement view)
{
    if (_isDisposed)
        return;

    var viewRenderer = Platform.CreateRenderer(view);
    Platform.SetRenderer(view, viewRenderer);

    var uiview = Renderer.NativeView;
    uiview.AddSubview(viewRenderer.NativeView);

    if (Renderer.ViewController != null && viewRenderer.ViewController != null)
        Renderer.ViewController.AddChildViewController(viewRenderer.ViewController;

    EnsureChildrenOrder();
}
```

So it looks like supposed to work, but layout classes like Grid are using DefaultRenderer which does not return ViewController and at this point the hierarchy becomes broken :(

I need to check if there is any way to override the renderer for Xamarin layout classes in order to restore view controllers chain.

Comment: did you manage to do this yet? I am currently having a similar issue, trying to attach the controller i am creating in my renderer to the parent renderer which should be provided by XF

Comment: I have failed to find a fix for the broken view controller chain so I have decided to present the view controller on the top of RootView controller, something like this: this.View.Window.RootViewController.PresentViewController(searchController, true, null);

Comment: thanks for letting me know. Using Platform.GetRenderer() on elements it's possible to navigate through parent controllers btw. that didn't help me fix my issue though